# Dynamically adding roles to a user

Tags: symfony, user-roles

We are using Symfony2's roles feature to restrict users' access to certain parts of our app. Users can purchase yearly subscriptions and each of our `User` entities has many `Subscription` entities that have a start date and an end.

Now, is there a way to dynamically add a role to a user based on whether they have an 'active' subscription? In rails i would simply let the model handle whether it has the necessary rights but I know that by design symfony2 entities are not supposed to have access to Doctrine.

I know that you can access an entity's associations from within an entity instance but that would go through ***all*** the user's subscription objects and that seems unnecessaryly cumbersome to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you would do better setting up a custom voter and attribute.

```
/**
 * @Route("/whatever/")
 * @Template
 * @Secure("SUBSCRIPTION_X")
 */
public function viewAction()
{
    // etc...
}
```

The `SUBSCRIPTION_X` role (aka attribute) would need to be handled by a custom voter class.

```
class SubscriptionVoter implements VoterInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function supportsAttribute($attribute)
    {
        return 0 === strpos($attribute, 'SUBSCRIPTION_');
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
    {
        // run your query and return either...
        //  * VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED
        //  * VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN
        //  * VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED
    }
}
```

You would need to configure and tag your voter:

```
services:
    subscription_voter:
        class: SubscriptionVoter
        public: false
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter }
```

Comment: @webda2l I don't understand your question

Comment: Sorry.. I'll try to be a little easier to understand.
The Voter class, which induced a query, is called only once by user or at each page load?
In this last case, to avoid the repetition of the query, the best way will be to manage with session in the vote function, isn't it?

Comment: You can add a caching mechanism or optimize as you see fit.

Comment: thank you so much! I hadn't looked into nor heard of voters before. I always find sf2's more interesting features to be scarcely documented and the very basic stuff way too much so.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the right relation "subscriptions" in your User Entity.

You can maybe try something like :

```
public function getRoles()
{
    $todayDate = new DateTime();
    $activesSubscriptions = $this->subscriptions->filter(function($entity) use ($todayDate) {
        return (($todayDate >= $entity->dateBegin()) && ($todayDate < $entity->dateEnd()));
    });

    if (!isEmpty($activesSubscriptions)) {
        return array('ROLE_OK');
    }

    return array('ROLE_KO');
}
```

Changing role can be done with :

```
$sc = $this->get('security.context')
$user = $sc->getToken()->getUser();
$user->setRole('ROLE_NEW');
// Assuming that "main" is your firewall name :
$token = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$sc->setToken($token);
```

But after a page change, the refreshUser function of the provider is called and sometimes, as this is the case with EntityUserProvider, the role is overwrite by a query.
You need a custom provider to avoid this.

Comment: I know. But as I said, I'd rather not go through all the subscription objects but let MySQL do the 'heavy lifting', since this has to happen on every request. (I never tested this, but it just seems slower to me to needlessly hydrate a bunch of objects. Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: You can use the success_handler option of form_login, to use an service with access to Doctrine.
Inside it, in onAuthenticationSuccess function, you do the request for get the right role.
And, because, roles are reload with each page change, you use an custom user provider which doesn't refresh user.

Comment: But would a user not have to log out and back in again should the roles change during a session? I wouldn't want that.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can force a user to change its roles without logout.

Comment: +1 for 2nd code snippet. Was stuck for ages wondering why just adding a role into my `User` entity was failing the `hasRole()` check. The roles property is almost pointless in Symfony, it's the token that's source of truth