# How to store Symfony2 "access_control" information in Database?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony2 and I have users and roles already stored in my DB. If I set something like below in `security.yml` it works great:

```
access_control:
   - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN}
   - { path: ^/users, role: ROLE_MANAGER}
```

But I would like to store this access_control information in the database, so the user from my system can change the permissions itself by using the administrative interface.

I looked at ACL and FOSUserBundle but could not find a solution for this. I found that I could check permissions with something like `if ($user->hasRole($role))` but I would need to do this in every controller.

Is there a way to define a dynamic "access_control" feature? Maybe something like redirecting the access_control to some class that could return true or false.
Any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way would be to setup a specific role (e.g. `DB_ROLE_CHECK`) that you set on your actions/services that you want validated against your database stored roles.

Then you would create a security voter that hooks into `DB_ROLE_CHECK` and validates your request against your database entries.

See:

- [Dynamically adding roles to a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879221/dynamically-adding-roles-to-a-user)
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html (Official Docs)

Comment: I didn't get it. Where I need to place role DB_ROLE_CHECK in roles hierarchy and how to check route in Voter? For example I have DB entries like [route, roles]. And in access_control rule ^/ : DB_ROLE_CHECK, right? So it will execute DBVoter on every request. In $attribute I will have role, then $token. And I will have a route or path as $subject param then? So I need get DB record by path and use it's role with $user from $token in a decisionManager, right?

Answer (score 3):

The access map is built [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.1/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L170).

If no access_control is found, nothing is done.

Now, define your own implementation of the [AccessMapInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.1/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/AccessMapInterface.php) and override the parameter [security.access_map.class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.1/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security_listeners.xml#L33) with your class.

You will probably need a factory to build your AccessMap.

Comment: I am trying to do it, but please, how can i override the security.access_map.class parameter ? I tried putting this in security.yml: security:  access_map:  class: CRM\CoreBundle\Security\DBAccessMap