# Specific access to url by function in access control

Tags: security, symfony

I need to find a way to set access to url by function.

For example, Can I set 'access control' in security.yml this way:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin$, function: checkadmin() }
```

In the other words, symfony run 'checkadmin()' function, and that function return a boolean value , so check access the path.

Or exist other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide a `role` when configuring an access control rule. That part of the security bundle (authorization) only cares about matching requests with required roles.

With that concrete rule, define a custom role like so:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin$, role: CHECK_ADMIN }
```

Then the question becomes, how can I dynamically add a role to a user?

The answer is a **Security Voter**:

- http://kriswallsmith.net/post/15994931191/symfony2-security-voters (best explination)
- [Dynamically adding roles to a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879221/dynamically-adding-roles-to-a-user/8883269)
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html