# Manage security/routing with Symfony2 by requesting a database

Tags: symfony, routes

Using **Symfony2**, I'm looking for a way to easily access the main route prefix for a given request, outside any controller:

I am trying to figure out the best way to deal with access control related to some database elements in Symfony2.

I would like to restrict the access to some 'applications' located in the path `/application/APP_ID` according to the `Subscription` stored in the database.
Every restricted resource will be in this path.

The subscriptions are referencing a User entity and an Application entity. It includes an ending date. After this ending date, the application should not be accessible anymore.

The restriction should be : for every resource starting with `/application/APP_ID`, I need to check if the controller should be accessed.
This prefix is static and is actually defined in the app/config/routing.yml as a 'prefix' and the corresponding route name is stored in one of the Application entity attributes. The other involved routes are defined in an independent routing.yml file located for example in `MyAppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` and imported in the main routing file.

Can I easily know if the current route requested (ex. /application/APP_ID/action/1) is included in the route defining the prefix (ex. /application/APP_ID) in order to know what Application is concerned?

Or, is there a way to do that without having to give a list of routes or paths which necessarily require modifications for every application added, route added or modified?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your problem, but on your "/application/APP_ID/action/1" route, is the "APP_ID/action/1" stored in database ? Or only the APP_ID ?

Comment: Actually, the **route name** redirecting to /application/APP_ID/ (the prefix) is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to develop your own Voter ? As explained here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html.

Instead of testing $request->getClientIp, you could test $request->getRequestUri. And you could have an access to doctrine, using $this->container->get('doctrine'). I think you could have all informations you need to secure your paths.

I did it few days ago to store my own RoleHierachy in database, it works well.

Comment: If you store in the database the APP_ID and the user authorizations, you should be able to retrieve the APP_ID from the kernel request, for example you could use a preg_match to extract the APP_ID and test if the user in the token is allowed to access the APP_ID, using doctrine. I'm not sure you can use the router here. But I'm not sure I understood your problem. Could you send an extract of your routing file ?

Comment: I misunderstood your first answer, and it does resolve my problem as well as this post does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879221/dynamically-adding-roles-to-a-user/8883269. I did not entirely understand the concept of the Voter and I thought it was only a partial solution. Thanks for you help!